# Draw outline with core-graphics

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-graphics, quartz-graphics

can anybody tell me how to draw an outline
on a UIButton with core-graphics?

I want the outline to look like on the link below

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/412741/test/Bildschirmfoto%202012-03-21%20um%2010.59.44.png

edit:

the image is from a wwdc 2011 Session Video
practical drawing for IOS Developers, but there is unfortunately no demo for that kind of outline

edit2:

Is there a property for the stroke of the outline?

Answer (score 0):

My idea would be create an imageview with image with the border(shown in the image) you want.
Place your button on top of the imageview so that the border is visible.

Comment: I had the same idea but I have buttons with dynamic hight, so Images won't work :-(

Comment: Can't you increase the imageview height along with button height.

Comment: I could do that, but the image would get stretched

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 3.0**

```
 class BorderButton: UIButton {
        override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
            super.draw(rect)
            let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
            context?.setStrokeColor(UIColor.red.cgColor)
            context?.setLineWidth(5.0)
            context?.stroke(bounds)
        }
    }
```